# Не могу задать диву фон картинкой

Tags: html, css

Может я чего недопонял или ошибка где и увидеть не могу, но обычный `background-color` работает, а картинку вставить не могу. И еще вопрос влияет ли размер картинки надо ее резать или сужать или браузер ее сам сожмет?

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  background: url(/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/12346.png)no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--start header-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header1"></div>
    <!--start logo-->
    <div class="logo flex-container1">
      <div class="logo-block">
        <a class="imag">
          <img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test/picturies   /logo.png" alt="" />
        </a>
        <!--start menu-->
        <div class="menu">
          <nav>
            <ul class="hr">
              <li><a class="text flex-item" href="#menu5" style="text-decoration:none">text</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="text flex-item" href="#menu4" style="text-decoration:none">text</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="text flex-item" href="#menu3" style="text-decoration:none">text</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="text flex-item" href="#menu2" style="text-decoration:none">text</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="text flex-item" href="#menu1" style="text-decoration:none">text</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <!--END menu-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--END logo-->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: проверьте путь к картинке. Первое, что бросается в глаза это название папки на русском языке. Если у вас картинка лежит в папке рядом с css, то вам достаточно писать  background: url(12346.png) no-repeat center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте путь к картинке. Первое, что бросается в глаза это название папки на русском языке. Если у вас картинка лежит в папке рядом с css, то вам достаточно писать

`background: url(12346.png) no-repeat center;`

Посмотрите [пример](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5hQLJMCTjRSFBPOE9WX2J5NmM/view?usp=sharing)

Если картинка лежит на одну папку выше, чем css, то вам нужно

```
background: url(../12346.png) no-repeat center;
```

На второй вопрос: размер картинки будет грузится полный, поэтому лучше сжимать картинку самому до минимальных размеров.

Comment: Спасибо большое очень сильно помогли, уже 3 часа пыхтел думал что не так=)

Answer (score 0):

**"url(...Рабочий стол...)"** что это?
А пробел кто убирать из пути будет?
Вот вам наглядный пример с кодом:

```css
#backgnd
{
  width:266px;
  height:136px;
  border: solid 1px #666666;
background-image: url(http://www.fountainbowl.com/images/background/Proper-Parchment.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div id="backgnd"></div>
```

А `<a class="imag">` это что за изобретение?

P.S. И кстати, начинающим очень полезен будет [этот ресурс](https://webref.ru/css/background-image). Сам там до сих пор что-то посматриваю.

Comment: пробел появился здесь при вводе кода в комментарии в самом коде его не было но все равно спасибо=)

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов, я не про второй пробел, я про `Рабочий[пробел]стол`.

Comment: Да понял спасибо=)